# Count occurrences of each permutation of bits in lists from CSV

Tags: python

Novice here, looking for a neater way to process some data with Python.

I have lists of 0's and 1's with lengths ranging from 2 - 10 digits in a CSV file.  I want to count the number of occurrences of each permutation in that CSV.

Is there a succinct way of doing this?

Here's what I have:

```
LL = float(0)
LW = float(0)
WL = float(0)
WW = float(0)    

with open('filename.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
        my_content = csv.reader(csvfile)

        for row in my_content:
            if not row:
                continue
            else:
                if len(row) == 2:
                    if row == ['0', '0']:
                        LL += 1
                    if row == ['0', '1']:
                        LW += 1
                    if row == ['1', '1']:
                        WW += 1
                    if row == ['1', '0']:
                        WL += 1
```

etc. for rows of each length...

This works for 2 bits, but I'm hoping there's another way to do the longer lists.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects) for this. As it's implemented on a dictionary, you will need to make your (mutable `list`) rows into (immutable) `tuple`s to use them:

```
from collections import Counter

count = Counter(map(tuple, my_content))
```

Example:

```
>>> data = [['0', '0'], ['0', '1', '0'], ['0', '0']]
>>> count = Counter(map(tuple, data))
>>> count
Counter({('0', '0'): 2, ('0', '1', '0'): 1})
```

This saves you from defining separate variables for each thing you want to count or manually creating and incrementing a dictionary and gives you access to handy extra features like [`.most_common(n)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common).

Comment: `Counter` is a great idea!

Comment: This worked perfectly.  Inspector gadget's tip worked as well, but I gave this answer the check-mark because the bins are in chronological order (with G4dget's, they are in order of occurrence).  I expect that those extra features will be of great use as well.  You guys saved me lots of time; thank you!!

Comment: Actually, neither @inspectorG4dget's answer nor mine guarantees any order, as they are both dictionary-based.

Comment: So the order of the bins may change if run on different data?  Is there any way to guarantee that the order stays the same?  I'm currently getting [00,01,10,11, etc...]

Comment: If you want to retain insertion order, you will have to use [`collections.OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects) instead. However, you may find that you don't need to worry about the order.

Answer (score 2):

This should give you a dictionary that maps the permutations to their counts

```
import collections
import csv

answer = collections.defaultdict(int)
with open('filename.csv') as infile:
    for row in csv.reader(infile):
        answer[''.join(row)] += 1
```

If you were to run this code on your example, you would have a dictionary that looks something like this:

```
answer = {'00' : 1,
          '01' : 1,
          '10' : 1,
          '11' : 1,
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, instead of float(0), you can just have "LL = 0.0". The decimal point indicates it is float. Anyway, you don't need floats, so you can just use integers.

Next, you don't need the my_content variable. Just have "for row in csv.reader(csvfile)".

Also, having a single dictionary instead of four variables would be better. You can have something like "binCounts = {'00': 0, '01': 0, '10': 0, '11': 0}" and instead of the code from "if len(row) == 2:" and on, just have code like this:

if ''.join(row) in binCounts:
  binCounts[''.join(row)] += 1

However, you mention that the numbers in the csv file can be 2 to 10 digits. This will only count the lines that are **exactly** two digits. Could you give an example of what your csv file looks like?

Comment: I used the jonsharpe answer above, but wanted to thank you for the float and csv tips!  (the lines in the csv look like ['0','1','0','0'] etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you are attempting to get a count of all binary numbers shown in the csv file. The best way would seem to be to create a dictionary with the keys the actual numbers and the values the count.

Assume you have created a function parserow() [left as an exercise for the student (:-)], taking the row of 1's and 0's and returning the equivalent of that value. Alternatively you can return the actual joined string if (for example) '0001' is considered different from '01' or '000001'

I will assume that you want the count over the entire content file

```
countdict = {}
for row in my_content:
    outval = parserow(row)
    if outval not in countdict.keys():
      countdict[outval] = 0
    countdict[outval] += 1
```

This should then give you a dictionary consisting of all the possibilities that have been found. You can even have an error entry in the dicitionary to show how many rows had illegal values.